# How do I select the next column instead of the next row when copying and pasting an Excel Formula to the end of a column?

Tags: excel, statistics, rows

So my formula is `=SUMPRODUCT(--(RawData!B2:B5580=TRUE))/COUNTA(RawData!B2:B5580)`. and when I copy it down it does this-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RawData!B3:B5581=TRUE))/COUNTA(RawData!B3:B5581)
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RawData!B4:B5582=TRUE))/COUNTA(RawData!B4:B5582)
```

etc.

What I want is for the next row (the one below the original equation) to select the next column instead of the next row. This is what I'm looking for-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RawData!B2:B5580=TRUE))/COUNTA(RawData!B2:B5580)
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RawData!C2:C5580=TRUE))/COUNTA(RawData!C2:C5580)
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RawData!D2:D5580=TRUE))/COUNTA(RawData!D2:D5580)
```

I've scoured the internet to no avail. Please help if you can. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(RawData!$B$2:$XFD$5580,0,ROW(A1))=TRUE)/COUNTA(INDEX(RawData!$B$2:$XFD$5580,0,ROW(A1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I solved my problem in a different way. I just tried this one and it didn't work.

Comment: 1.  What does not work?  It works for me.  2.  How did you solve it, If you used OFFSET or INDIRECT, Note that those are volatile.

Comment: Are you using google sheets?  It should work over multiple sheets just fine.  Did you change the formula?  If so what formula did you paste?

Comment: Ohhhhh ok I see what I did wrong. You're selecting the whole table and then iterating over the rows. I get it now. It's excel by the way.

Comment: I still can't figure it out

Comment: Are you changing the formula or just copy paste.  It should just copy paste into the first cell, then copy down.

Comment: Also which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: It's Excel 2016. I just tried it again and it worked but when I tried to make it rely on multiple values for the percentage (`...ROW(A2:C2)...`) it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Yes you can only do one column at a time.  You did not state that was a requirement in your question.  I suggest you ask a new question with the new requirements.

Comment: I just need one column at a time. Give me a few more minutes to try this out again. There's no need to ask a new question.

Comment: If you only need one column do not change the formula.  Just put it in the first cell and copy down.

Comment: Ok. So it works, but when I try sorting from largest to smallest, although it gets the feature right, it doesn't change the values in the cells.

Comment: It won't unless you copy paste the numbers as values only or you hard code the column individually in each formula.  Formulas are live

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve this. Take your lookup table (the one with the values you're looking to sum for a percentage). Take only the fields that you want to filter on. Select those fields and paste them into one sheet (MainSheet). After you've pasted the fields you want to filter on, select the rest of that table and copy it. Make another sheet (RawData) and paste it **tranposed**. That's the very important part there. When you right-click and have your paste options, select the one that looks like it's rotating a tetris block to the left; that is your transpositional pasting button.

Now that you have your Lookup table, your RawData Table, and your MainSheet, you can simply copy the transposed column headers and paste them next to your selected columns on the MainSheet. Note now that when you filter those fields the transposed columns will disappear and reappear with those selects.

Now that all that has been done, put your formula in the cell next to your transposed column header (`=SUMPRODUCT(--(RawData!A4:HFP4=TRUE))/COUNTA(RawData!A4:HFP4)`). After doing that, copy and paste it all the way down to the end of your transposed columns and, if you want to be fancy, make it a percentage by selecting `Percentage` from the number box in the Home tab.

Good luck and have fun!